# Validación de formulario con Jquery no funciona

Tags: jquery

Estoy intentando validar el siguiente formulario con Jquery, pero no me lo valida, directamente si le doy al botón enviar, me lo  envia aunque esten los campos vacios. Estoy guiándome a través de la página https://jqueryvalidation.org/
El código del formulario:

```html
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>"> 


Nombre: <br>
<input type="text" name="first_name" required><br>
Apellido:<br>
 <input type="text" name="last_name" required><br>
Email:<br> <input type="email" name="email" required><br>
Mensaje:<br><textarea rows="5" name="message" cols="30" required></textarea><br>
Seleccionar fecha:<br>
    <input id="datepicker" name="fecha"  required>
  
   
            <br>
            Reservar hora:<br>
           <select name="time" required>
                                    <option value="">Reservar hora</option>
                                     <option value="9:00-10:00">09:00 - 10:00</option>
                                    <option value="10:15-11:15">10:15 - 11:15</option>
                                    <option value="11:30-12:30">11:30 - 12:30</option>
                                    </select> 
           <input name="idprofesor1" type="hidden" value="prof"> 
             <input name="online" type="hidden" value="Madrid"> 
             
       <p></p> 
 
<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">
  <input type="checkbox" required> Acepto la <a href="https://www.web.es/politica-privacidad.php">Política de Privacidad</a>  de <a href="https://www.web.es">WEb</a>

  <div>
  <input class="btn_env" type="submit" name="submit" value="Enviar">  
<input class="borr" type="reset" value="Borrar">
</div>
  
</form>
```

Hago la llamada las librerias dentro de mi propio servidor para los archivos jquery.validate.js y jquery.js desde la etiqueta de cierre

```js
<br>
    <script src="https://www.web.es/archivos/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.web.es/archivos/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("form").validate();
    </script>
```

Si quito los enlaces a las librerias si me lo valida, sin embargo con los plugin no surte efecto.

Al final leyendo la  documentación e indicando que el hotlinking esta permitido he sustituido  el código anterior despues de la etiqueta de cierre  por el enlace externo.

```js
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.5/dist/jquery.validate.js">
</script>
```

Corrijanme si me equivoco pero ahora parece que funciona ok